# How to Pause onedrive sync on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I have OneDrive running on my Windows 8.1 and I put many files in its folder to sync with online, Sometimes I need to pause this sync, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On OneDrive (non business) you can pause sync but it is a bit hidden.

In Windows File Explorer, in the tree view, if you right click on one of the OneDrive root icons, there is an option to pause synchronisation in the menu.

These root icons will appear

- in your file tree wherever you have put the OneDrive files
- under Libraries>Documents
- under Desktop (might be windows 8 only)

It does NOT appear on the status bar icon, which is really strange.

[image: Pause OneDrive]

Comment: no longer works :(

Comment: works again, see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

In this week's version, you can stop syncing by right clicking the OneDrive system tray icon and clicking "Exit".

Let's hope Microsoft fix this nonsense soon.

Answer (score 1):

The latest update allows pausing and resuming by right clicking the system tray icon.

Answer (score 1):

OneDrive asked me to upgrade itself last week and the pause sync seems to be back! You can even choose the time for resume syncing automatically (2, 8 or 24h). This is OneDrive personal, Version 2016 (Build 17.3.6517.0809).

Hurray!

[image: system tray context menu]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pause the sync, but you can temporarily deactivate it:

- You want to open the OneDrive App.
- Then swipe from the right edge of the screen, select Settings. (or
  move the mouse to the bottom edge of the screen, then move up and
  select Settings)
- Click on Options and deactivate Sync Files.