# Pause OneDrive sync using cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, sync, cmd.exe, onedrive

I would like to know how to pause onedrive from syncing using a command in the cmd. I am doing this because I have my .minecraft folder shared in onedrive and when I am playing minecraft, it is really slow and onedrive tries to sync the data that is being used. Right now I have to pause it with right clicking the folder and clicking pause but I would like to know the code to stop it with cmd so I can made a .bat file to pause onedrive and then start minecraft. If anyone knows how to do this, please let me know.

Thanks,
Kyle5953c

Comment: I am not aware of a method to control OneDrive from just a command console by itself.  You can pause it through [windows explorer](http://superuser.com/questions/751453/how-to-pause-onedrive-sync-on-windows-8-1?rq=1) though.

Comment: You can write an AutoIt/AHK script I suppose to automate the right-clicking and pausing, then execution of Minecraft. As for script access to OneDrive sync directly, perhaps it's possible via PowerShell and the Live API: [1](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/07/01/use-powershell-3-0-to-get-more-out-of-windows-live.aspx), [2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/07/02/use-powershell-to-work-with-skydrive-for-powerful-automation.aspx), [3](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/04/07/using-the-windows-live-apis-from-powershell/).

Comment: I don't have a window s8.1 machine in front of me, but I'm pretty sure OneDrive still uses `skydrive.exe` in the \windows\system32\ folder.  Try `skydrive /shutdown` to stop it...

Comment: You can also use `process -s onedrive.exe` from beyondlogic to sleep the process. You run the same command line to resume.

Comment: Have you tried: taskkill /f /im (onedrive's sync process)?

Answer (score 5):

A more graceful way to stop OneDrive than TASKILL or PSSUSPEND is:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe /shutdown
```

Answer (score 4):

You can stop it by running a batch file that will loop so it will stop onedrive until you exit:

```
:Loop
Taskkill /f /im onedrive.exe
Goto loop
```

If you want to do it manually, then simply just do Taskkill /f /im onedrive.exe

Please run this batch file once you have started minecraft.
**Tested on Windows 7**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I solved it as follows:
Suspend (shutdown) Onedrive:

```
"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive" /shutdown
```

Resume Onedrive:

```
start "OneDrive" /B "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive" /background
```

Without the start command, Onedrive becomes a subtask of your batch command, and it never comes back. /background suppresses user prompts

Comment: I found that 1) OneDrive command line switches must be all LOWER-CASE. e.g., Worked: "/background" and "/shutdown". DID NOT WORK: "/Background" and "/Shutdown".  2) Use combination "/background /shutdown" to prevent the File Explorer window popping up during shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

Use pssuspend
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pssuspend

`pssuspend onedrive
minecraft
pssuspend -r onedrive`