# Onedrive has disappeared from system tray icons after clicking 'exit' (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, sync, taskbar, onedrive

I wanted to pause my Onedrive temporarily and followed the advice on this thread [How to Pause onedrive sync on windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/751453/how-to-pause-onedrive-sync-on-windows-8-1/997928#997928) to click "exit". It has indeed stopped syncing, but it has also disappeared from the system tray icons. I'm afraid I can't get it to start again and I can't work out how to get it back in the tray. (Have tried to get it to show again by clicking on it in the "select which icons appear on the taskbar" section under Taskbar and Start Menu Properties, but to no avail.)

Any ideas how to get it back? And does anyone know a quick way to turn Onedrive sync on and off?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Exit" has quit the application. To re-start synchronization you must run OneDrive again. It worked for me. Choose one of the following:

- `win`+R to open the `run command` textbox, then type `onedrive` and hit `return`
- Windows Menu (with `win` key) then `All apps` and scroll down to "O" then click `OneDrive`

A pop-up notification will tell you that OneDrive is running and it will show again in the windows tray (may be in the "hidden icons" set).

Answer (score 0):

Search onedrive and open it. It will be located in the taskbar again.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to search for OneDrive at the bottom of your screen where it says "Search the Web and Windows".

Just open it and the sync should restart.